How is PCM data transferred from hardware to DMA in ALSA, and how can I modify it before user space access?
I am trying to understand how PCM data is transferred from hardware to DMA in ALSA when recording. Specifically, I would like to modify the PCM data before it is read by user space. I am interested in modifying the data directly in DMA.
Here are my questions:
1.What functions are responsible for transferring PCM data from the hardware to DMA in ALSA?
2.Where should I intercept or modify the data in the ALSA driver to achieve this?
3.Are there any recommended functions or hooks within ALSA for modifying PCM data at the DMA       level?

What I’ve tried:
I first attempted to modify the __snd_pcm_lib_xfer function, but it had no effect. Then, I used trace-cmd to trace the Linux kernel function calls and found that the snd_pcm_update_hw_ptr0 function is frequently called. I investigated how old_hw_ptr, new_hw_ptr, and hw_base work, and tried to modify them, but it didn’t give the desired result.
I am struggling with how to traverse the PCM data within the DMA. Later, I noticed that the snd_pcm_set_runtime_buffer function is called at the start of recording, so I added printk logs to inspect the DMA buffer details.
static inline void snd_pcm_set_runtime_buffer(struct snd_pcm_substream *substream,
                          struct snd_dma_buffer *bufp)

{
    struct snd_pcm_runtime *runtime = substream->runtime;
    if (bufp) {
        printk(KERN_INFO "Setting DMA buffer for substream: %s\n", substream->name);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Buffer area (virtual address): %p\n", bufp->area);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Buffer address (physical address): %llx\n", (unsigned long long)bufp->addr);
        printk(KERN_INFO "Buffer size: %zu bytes\n", bufp->bytes);

        runtime->dma_buffer_p = bufp;
        runtime->dma_area = bufp->area;
        runtime->dma_addr = bufp->addr;
        runtime->dma_bytes = bufp->bytes;
    } else {

        printk(KERN_INFO "Clearing DMA buffer for substream: %s\n", substream->name);
        
        runtime->dma_buffer_p = NULL;
        runtime->dma_area = NULL;
        runtime->dma_addr = 0;
        runtime->dma_bytes = 0;
    }

    // 打印运行时最终的 DMA 信息
    printk(KERN_INFO "Runtime DMA area: %p\n", runtime->dma_area);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Runtime DMA addr: %llx\n", (unsigned long long)runtime->dma_addr);
    printk(KERN_INFO "Runtime DMA bytes: %zu\n", runtime->dma_bytes);
}

Here's a sample of the output I got:
Setting DMA buffer for substream: subdevice #0
Buffer area (virtual address): 00000000b77507ac
Buffer address (physical address): 0
Buffer size: 356352 bytes
Runtime DMA area: 00000000b77507ac
Runtime DMA addr: 0
Runtime DMA bytes: 356352

However, I’m now stuck and unsure how to proceed with modifying or accessing PCM data directly within the DMA buffer.
Additionally, I read online that I might need to use dmaengine, but I found that it wasn’t invoked at all in my case, which leaves me confused about its role in the data transfer process.
From what I understand so far, the PCM data is first stored in the DMA buffer and then mapped to user space via mmap, rather than being copied to user space using copy_to_user (though I’m not entirely sure). This makes me wonder if there’s a way to intercept the data before the mmap operation.
